# Python: Где нужно указать имя человека

Tags: python, request

Мой код

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'Секретный ключ',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'query': '{string}',
    'page': '{integer}',
    'limit': '{integer}',
})
try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('services.api1881.no')
    conn.request("GET", "/search/{type}?%s" % params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Мне нужно оправить как запрос имя человека:
https://services.api1881.no/search/unit?query=John smitt

Я не понимаю в каком поле указывается имя человека
Я мало разбираюсь в питон, дайте пожалуйста готовый ответ с кодом

Comment: Если судить по пути, на который Вы собираетесь сделать запрос, то "John smitt" относится к полю `query`, насколько мне кажется

Comment: try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('services.api1881.no')
    conn.request("GET", "/lookup/id/{id}?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

За что отвечает {body}?

Answer (score 0):

На примере requests

```
params = {
    "query": "John smitt"
}
headers = {
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": key
}

url = 'https://services.api1881.no/search/unit'
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

Про page и limit, не понятно или в params или в заголовках (headers) должны передаваться?
```